# cordova build --release android does not give me a unsigned apk

Tags: android, cordova

Whenever I run `cordova build --release android` it does not give me an unsigned.apk like it's supposed to.  Instead it gives me a `android-x86-release.apk`.  Here is the output:

[image]

Last time I did this I got a `android-release-unsigned.apk`but now all of a sudden it's not creating it.  I tried to sign the `android-x86-release.apk` file and the `android-arm7-release-unsigned.apk` files but I got an error saying `jarsigned:unable to open jar file: <FILE_NAME>`